# How to make all children in a flex-container to have the same height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am stuck with this problem.

I am trying to make all the child divs within a flex container to have the same height as the tallest child div,here it is 100px and i want them to be aligned center

not sure how can i do it. I tried flex:1 did not work, i tried doing align:stretch too but does not seem to work.

can some one please help on this.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  align-items: center;
  height:160px;
}
.container div:not(:first-child) {
  background: green;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;

}
.container div:first-child {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    item-1
  </div>
  <div>
    item-2
  </div>
  <div>
    item-3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you just need to wrap your inner `div`'s in another `div` and set `align-items: center` on `container` element.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
}
div > div {
  display: flex;
}
.container div div:not(:first-child) {
  background: green;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.container div div:first-child {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      item-1
    </div>
    <div>
      item-2
    </div>
    <div>
      item-3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: justify-content:flex-end it defines on main axis..i am looking something for cross-axis flex-end

Comment: It depends on flex-direction.

Comment: ya it does ...here flex-direction:row,im looking for align-items:flex-end but with all items should take the tallest item's height

Comment: You don't have height set on container so height depends on tallest item so all items will be by default aligned to bottom of container.

Comment: oh ya..i got it..I have modified my question ,actually when it has to be align-items:center and all items have to be equal height how can we do that

Comment: So its center not bottom?

Comment: Easiest and i am afraid the only way to do that is to wrap your inner div in one more div so you get this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1301/

Comment: yaa i got it ...this is perfect for me...thanks a lot...i was confused a little but this helped me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127668/discussion-between-geeky-and-nenad-vracar).